# How to show selected checkbox in multiselect checkbox list in laravel?

Tags: laravel, multi-select, multichoiceitems, jquery-ui-multiselect

I have a multi-select checkbox list. I want to show stored value in list using checkbox selected.

User informations are stored in **Partner_Prefence** table and user religion column named as **p_religion**

```
$profile_data= DB::table('partner_prefence')->select('p_religion')->first();
```

Fetching religions from religions table

```
$religion_data=DB::table('religion')->select('religion_id','religion_name')->orderby('religion_name')->get();
```

Multiselect list

```
<select  multiple="multiple" name="religion[]">
   @foreach($religion_data as $religion)
     <option value="{{$religion->religion_id}}" {{$profile_data->p_religion == $religion->religion_id  ? 'selected' : ''}}>{{$religion->religion_name}}</option>
   @endforeach
</select>
```

I'm having trouble with showing which religions user have

```
{{$profile_data->p_religion == $religion->religion_id  ? 'selected' : ''}}
```

Comment: can you show us how you store selected religions id ?

Comment: also please dump and show us profile_data with dd method. example `dd($profile_data)`

Comment: @HasanTıngır $religion = $request->input('religion');
    $religion = implode(',', $religion);
    DB::table('partner_prefence')->insert(['p_marital_status' => $relationship_status, 'p_religion' => $religion]);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as I understand you have multi select form, so you need show selected multiple column..

You're storing ids as a string but it's hard check that certain number in string. İf you convert string into a array, you can easly check with `in_array()` method. This method will return true if given value exist in given array

```
<select multiple="multiple" name="religion[]">
    {{-- no need to explode every time, it will reduce your performance --}}
    @php($religions = explode(',', $profile_data->p_religion))
    @foreach($religion_data as $religion)
        <option
                value="{{$religion->religion_id}}"
                {{--if user religion id exist in religions then mark as selected--}}
                {{in_array($religion->religion_id,$religions) ? "selected" : ""}}>
            {{$religion->religion_name}}
        </option>
    @endforeach
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Is the p_religion column saving multiple IDs if it is a multi-select list? Would using `in_array()` work then instead of using `$profile_data->p_religion == $religion->religion_id`.

`in_array ($religion->religion_id, explode(',', $profile_data->p_religion))`

*Added the `explode()` call on the off chance you are storing an imploded array.*

You could also try and use the blade syntax for an if statement inline to see if it displays differently.

```
<select  multiple="multiple" name="religion[]">
     @foreach($religion_data as $religion)
          <option value="{{$religion->religion_id}}" @if($profile_data->p_religion == $religion->religion_id) selected @endif>
               {{$religion->religion_name}}
          </option>
     @endforeach
</select>
```

Comment: how to write in_array ($religion->religion_id, explode(',', $profile_data->p_religion))  in blade syntax.

Comment: You could wrap it in the blade curly braces. It would really just replace the `==` part of your if statement.
`{{($religion->religion_id, explode(',', $profile_data->p_religion))  ? 'selected' : ''}}`